# Bootstrap collapsible panels- can't toggle .glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap collapsible panels and I'm trying to toggle the class of the glyphicon icon that's in the panel title when the panel expands. It works but it also changes all the other titles that aren't expanded. I've tried adding an if/else to check if the aria-expanded = true but that doesn't work either. Thanks for any assistance.

```
JS
        $('a.panel-toggle').on('click', function () {
             if ($('.panel-toggle').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
            $('.glyphicon').toggleClass("flip");
            }
        });

CSS
        .glyphicon   {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #720808;

        }
.glyphicon.glyphicon-play.flip {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

HTML
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> 

          <a data-toggle="collapse"  data-parent="#panel" href="#collapse1" class="panel-toggle">Group 1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" id="icontoggle"></span></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Sub-group 1</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Sub=group 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No need to use JS, this can be done purely with CSS working with the `collapsed` class. Here's a codepen for you to review http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/BQzpWP

Comment: Thanks - appreciate it.